# How to hide the button when the value exceeds specific amount

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i want to display the button only when the value does not exceed 25. My code looks like this. Value in my product list element is 25. And with each click I add 6 to my `input[name='skip]` element. What i'm doing wrong? Note that my `input[name='skip]`  is increasing with each click.

```
$(function () {
    $("#button-submit").click(function () {
        var $productList = $(".product-list");
        var $value = $("input[name='skip']");
        $value.val(parseInt($value.val()) + 6);
        if (parseInt($productList.val()) >= parseInt($value.val())) {
            $("#button-submit").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome! The HTML would be useful - what would be _most useful_ is if you created a runnable snippet.  Please see how to create an [mcve]

Comment: You should do opposite: if (parseInt($productList.val()) < parseInt($value.val())) { (I'm guessing here).

Comment: What is `.product-list`? Does it have a value? Are you sure? The code works fine, _assuming that_ `.product-list` has a value that is greater than the incremented `$value.val()`....

Comment: I think you should use `<` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is incorrect. So you should use `<` instead of `>=`

```js
$("#button-submit").click(function () {
  var $productList = $(".product-list");
  var $value = $("input[name='skip']");
  $value.val(parseInt($value.val()) + 6);
  if (parseInt($productList.val()) < parseInt($value.val())) {
    $("#button-submit").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="product-list" value="25">
<input type="text" name="skip" value="0">
<button type="button" id="button-submit">Click</button>
```

Also your code could be simpler

```
$("#button-submit").click(function () {
  var $value = $("input[name='skip']");
  $value.val(+$value.val() + 6);
  if (+$(".product-list").val() < +$value.val()) {
    $(this).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: It acutally helped, thanks a lot however i needed add id a custom attirbute as what i learned "DIVs do not have a value property". That is way the button didn't disappear. As the value was null for the Product List.

Answer (score 1):

you seem to have an error with the selector

`var $productList = $(".product-list']");`

should probably be something like

`var $productList = $(".product-list");`

Edit:
i think you might want to use

`$(".product-list").length` instead of  `$(".product-list").val()` since it looks like its a collection of items.

Just a guess tho as you havent provided the full markup.

Comment: While a good hunch, this is just a guess, given that OP hasn't included the target markup...

Comment: Sorry it was wrongly copied code. There is value attirbute in my div, which has the amount of all products. Having a collection propably won't work as those products are loaded dynamically with each click. So i wanted to compare Value from that div to skip parameter which increases with each click by 6. And when the skip exceed the amount of products, stop displaying the button.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to get the count of list items?  I have a sample for counting list items below.  Also, I noticed the comparison of productlist to value was backwords so I reversed the operator less than as opposed to greater than.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#button-submit").click(function() {
   
    // get number of list items
    var $productList = $('.product-list').children('li').length;
    var $value = $("input[name='skip']");
    //alert("value: "+$value.val());
    //alert("value: "+$value.val()+" productlist: " + $productList);
    $value.val(parseInt($value.val()) + 6);

    if ($productList <= parseInt($value.val())) {
      $("#button-submit").hide();
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="skip" value=0>
<button id="button-submit">Click</button>
<div class="product-list"></div>

<ul class="product-list">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Carrot</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
  <li>Watermelon</li>
  <li>Lemon</li>
  <li>Kiwi</li>
  <li>Grape</li>
</ul>
```